# Making element visible in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

As the title says.. is there a way to get it to work with IE?

I'm using:

```
document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility='visible';
```

For

```
<img id="loadingImage" src="images/25.gif" style="padding:0px;margin-bottom:-7px;visibility:hidden;">
```

But it isn't working. Thanks.

***Edit:***
Is is being called with list this [alert then reload page IN detect file extension upload script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260629/alert-then-reload-page-in-detect-file-extension-upload-script) :

```
function TestFileType( fileName, fileTypes ) {
if (!fileName) return;

dots = fileName.split(".")
//get the part AFTER the LAST period.
fileType = "." + dots[dots.length-1];

if (fileTypes.join(".").indexOf(fileType) != -1) {
   document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility='visible';
   return true;
} else {
   alert('Please select (.w3g) file only!');
   return false;
}
}
```

with

```
<input name="replay_file" id="replay_file" type="file" accept=".w3g*"/>
<input type="submit" id="upload_file" value="Upload" name="uploadReplay" onClick="return TestFileType(this.form.replay_file.value, ['w3g','.w3g']);" />
<img id="loadingImage" src="images/25.gif" style="padding:0px;margin-bottom:-7px;visibility:hidden;">
```

*PS: This is not a duplicate question as the others were not so related.*

Comment: How are you calling it? Are there errors? There is not enough details to tell you why.

Comment: This code works fine on its own: http://jsfiddle.net/3P2gX/ The problem is somewhere else. Are there any error messages in the console? Can you post the rest of the code around where you set the visibility?

Comment: You mention only IE - are you saying the same code works in other browsers? Is your script run _after_ the image element has been parsed? (I.e., is that line of code in a script block after the image and/or in an onload handler or other event handler run after the page is loaded?)

Comment: You have not disclosed enough of your code for us to know why it isn't working.  There is nothing wrong with the code you have if it is run at the right time and if there are no other errors in your page.  As nnnnnn said, you must run the `document.getElementById()` AFTER the page has loaded and you must make sure you have no other script errors that are stopping execution of your javascript before this statement executes.

Comment: If you can not make an element show by setting its CSS rule `visibility:visible` then make sure any of its parents is not set to hidden. Because if that's the case there's no way to make this child show. Also, make sure you don't have multiple elements in your page with the same unique name in their id attributes.

Comment: Also make sure that you didn't set display=none somewhere

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you `return true` right after changing the visibility, so the page gets submitted/reloaded..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about these 2 changes:

replace <strike>this.form.replay_file.value</strike> with:

```
document.getElementById('replay_file').value
```

and add the missing semicolon at the end of this line:

```
dots = fileName.split(".");
```

---

By the way, you take the second argument of the function as an array and join it to a string. why not pass it as a string to begin with?

Moreover, out of the 2 array members, 'w3g' will never match (only '.w3g' might match) because you always look up a string that begins with a dot...

And a recommendation: be consistent with the return type. If this function is expected to return a boolean, then the first line should be changed to:

```
if (!fileName) return false;
```

Comment: It seems after doing a triple check i found out that there was a div with the visibility somehow overriding and messing the loadingImage up for IE.. after adjusting that it works but with IE giving the error icon but after adjusting these `dots = fileName.split(".");` `document.getElementById('replay_file').value` the error is gone and now it works perfectly fine! thanks